# Ender3 printing flattened on X axis

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3

[image: Extruder_Knob]I'm fairly new to the amazing world of 3D printing, with an Ender3X.
Default model (the dog) worked very fine, but I'm experiencing some issues with some of the printer improvement parts I decided to print.

It seems to narrow the print on the X axis; a printed circle for instance will always have the correct shape, except on both extremities on X, where it will be flattened, no matter the size.

I experienced it with the extruder knob: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3176144
for which all dents were fine but the ones on the X axis sides. 
Also experienced it on the filament's guide torus: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2917932/

I'm having a hard time figuring out where I messed up; could it be related to a software mistake I would have made in Cura, a failed bed leveling or any other hardware issue like an over/under tightened X axis?

Thanks!

Comment: Without photos of what you are getting, it is difficult to say, but it sounds like a loose belt.

Comment: Please add photos and describe the "upgrades" you did. Without this information this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Picture added, sorry!
I'll try with a tightened X axis, thanks for your advice!

Comment: Tightening the belt was indeed the solution, thanks Mick!

Comment: Wow, it's impressive that you were able to get results that bad with a loose belt without it failing to print entirely.